# Export selected lines as GPX

Tags: leaflet, geojson, gpx

I have created an option in my Leaflet.js web map that exports clicked lines as GPX, but it is just exports only the last clicked line.
I need to export all clicked/highlighted/selected lines in one GPX file.

Here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('data/routes/Download/Nwn.geojson', function (collection) {
    Nwn = L.geoJson(collection, {
      'style': function () {
        return {
          'color': '#FFFF00',
          'weight': 3,
          'opacity': 0
        }
      }, onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('exportHiking').onclick = function() {
                var toJson = layer.toGeoJSON();
                var dGpx = togpx(toJson);
                document.getElementById('exportHiking').setAttribute('href', 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + dGpx);
                document.getElementById('exportHiking').setAttribute('download','route.gpx');
            };
        })
        var timesClicked = 0;
        layer.on('click', function() {
          Nwn.resetStyle(layer);
          layer.setStyle({color: '#FFFF00', opacity: 1});
          timesClicked++;
          if(timesClicked>1) {
            Nwn.resetStyle(layer);
            timesClicked = 0;
          }
        });
        //   Nwn.resetStyle(layer);
      },
      distanceMarkers: { showAll: 11, offset: 1000000, cssClass: 'some-other-class', iconSize: [16, 16] }
    }).addTo(NwnGroupe);
    map.addLayer(NwnGroupe);
});
```

How it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through layers in `NwnGroupe` layer group, check (by the color) which are selected ones, add them to JSON object and then convert to GPX:

```
document.getElementById('exportHiking').onclick = function() {
    var toJson = L.geoJSON();
    NwnGroupe.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      if (layer.options.color == '#FFFF00') {
        toJson.addData(layer.toGeoJSON());
      }
    });
    var dGpx = togpx(toJson);
    document.getElementById('exportHiking').setAttribute('href', 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + dGpx);
    document.getElementById('exportHiking').setAttribute('download','route.gpx');
};
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: I have tested it, but it can't read property of color.
So i have replaced "option" with "options", but it exports an empty GPX.
I am not sure it should be "option" or "options".

Comment: You are right, it's `options`. I modified my answer.

Comment: but it still not working, it exports an empty gpx file.

Comment: Then debug execution in browser (F12). Set breakpoint at  `if (layer.options.color == '#FFFF00')` statement and see what's actually happening there.

Comment: It shows this statement in the console (warning: unsupported geometry type: undefined), and exports an empty gpx file.
Is this an issue about getting selected lines as GeoJSON?
or about converting it into GPX?

Comment: Console messages will not be enough. In debugger you have to go through all the layers to see at which layer it fails and then check attributes of this layer.

Comment: i have tried, but maybe i don't know how to use debugger. could just help me with it?

Comment: If you want to do any serious programming, you'll have to learn debugging. There's a lot of resources on internet about that, just do some searching.

Comment: I have performed debugging on the function, but no errors.
it is seems to be an error occurred on geometry when converting multiple lines to GPX.